# Why after adding server time to this javascript countdown event timer it stopped working?

Tags: javascript, php

After I've added the code for getting date on the server and using it on the `var currdate` in the beginning of my script .. it stopped working and doesn't display any timer at all. What cause that? Something wrong in first 3 lines .. but what?

```
    <?php $d = date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?> // something wrong here?
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var currdate = new Date('<?php echo $d; ?>'); // or something wrong here?
..........................
    </script>
```

Comment: step 1: remove almost all this code because it has absolutely nothing to do with your problem, and you're just dumping source code on people and expecting them to know what you're doing. That's a little inconsiderate. Reduce your problem: can you write a php script that generates the JS that constructs the correct date object? That's going to be about 5 lines of code that you can try to make work. Once you do, a large part of your problem is gone and you can focus on the rest.

Comment: I understand, however, I find your comment to be rude just because you know what to do .. that doesn't mean I know too. If you don't want to be constructive and point me out where exactly the issue is coming from, please don't post on my request. Thanks!

Comment: when you click to post a question, there is a big box telling you how to ask a question, with a link to "asking help". I've read that page, you should have read that page too, because you saw that box and have used the site before (based on your user score). Whether you ignored it or not is another matter, and entirely your own responsibility.

Comment: So, what was your constructive comment here? Yeah, I might possibly improve my question but what you did other than spamming mostly?

Comment: @MokIk—you were given some excellent advice—reduce your code to the minimum that displays the issue and post that. That exercise in itself will often lead you to fix your own problem. If not, it is very much easier for others to fix and shows you've put some effort into it. For questions about client–side issues, post what the browser gets, not the server code that generates it.

Comment: I did reduced the code as you said. Thanks!

Comment: What does `<?php $d = date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>` generate? What does the browser get?

Comment: `var currdate = new Date('<?php echo $d; ?>'); // or something wrong here?` Very likely, using the Date constructor to parse strings is a bad idea, it's implementation dependent and unreliable. Far better to use a time value (e.g. UNIX seconds since epoch).

Comment: I get response on echo $d --> Wed Nov 26 2014 05:27:20 +0200

Answer (score 0):

@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans
 What he said...

PHP used in JavaScript and JavaScript used in PHP. It just doesn't work that way. Two, not only completely different languages, but more importantly one is client based while the other is server based. Please read up and learn for yourself. It is a lot easier than you think it as; Or maybe it isn't.

Comment: So, why all examples in stackoverflow suggest to use it similiar like I did in my `<script>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a date and time to the browser, far better to use a time value such as seconds since the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) since ECMAScript uses the same epoch. The difference is that javascript uses milliseconds, so to convert a time value in seconds to a javascript date:

```
var date = new Date(timeValueInSeconds * 1000);
```

Comment: But my current script below checks for which date and etc, so using unixtime stamp it cannot check what day is 7 (Sunday) right? Is it possible to pass it like unixtimestamp but after that convert it to date() format?

Comment: Actually I tested it: `new Date(1416972440 * 1000);` it works, but that: `new Date(<?php time();?> * 1000);` doesn't work ... why probably ?

Comment: So, by adding manually the unix timestamp it works correctly but if I include it as I showed above this post .. it doesn't. Why probably?

Comment: Any idea why is that?

Comment: What does the browser get?

Comment: It doesn't execute as php code still when I check the source after loading the page and it shows as it is: `new Date(<?php echo time(); ?> * 1000);` ... Why could be that?

Comment: @MokIk This is because, like I said below, PHP is a server side language and JavaScript is a client side language. Thus, calling a server side language function from a client side language method will not work.

Comment: So how to change my current script to call another Time.php with `time()` inside and get the server time? Will appreciate any help. Thanks!